# Is it possible to run Copy-VMFile powershell command as non-admin?

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I have a host machine with Hyper-V enabled, and I have a Hyper-V guest running on this machine. Becauze I can't drag&drop files to the VM, I wrote a script to do this for me, which is integrated in TotalCommander, and which uses [Copy-VMFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/copy-vmfile?view=win10-ps).

My problem is that the PS script works only if I run it as admin, otherwise I get the error "You do not have the required permission to complete this task."

Why do I need admin to copy from the host machine to the guest OS? And is there a way, some policy which would allow me to circumvent this? It is annoying to enter a password every time I want to copy some files.